# Should a page with adsense be viewed at least once for adsense crawler to crawl?

Tags: wordpress, web-crawlers, googlebot, google-adsense

I use plugins to insert Adsense codes on my WordPress website. The plugin has an option to disable ads for the admin user. Hence, I will not be seeing ads when creating and publishing/reviewing posts. When I visit the pages I have created, there will be no requests to Adsense servers.

When I visit my page an anonymous user for the first time, ads don't load most certainly. (But there will be requests to the Adsense server with single digit coverage.). But the ads appear during the subsequent visits (when refreshing the page or visiting after a while). Does that mean the page with Adsense has to be viewed in the browser at least once for Adsense crawler to visit and crawl the page?

I am asking this because Adsense crawler is different from google search bot.

Ref:https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/99376?hl=en

Unless someone visits the page in a browser there is no chance for Adsense crawler to know in advance that the page has Adsense codes in it.

Comment: The same things happens in approval requests if it does not request any page to crawl but we get the response from servers

Comment: No, it's not so, Adsense crawler will crawl your pages and capture all those pages which have adsense code to show ads on your web pages, to let Google saw ads make sure you have enough overall traffic on your website to earn good payouts.